# Joining SQL tables when 2nd table comes from SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, vba

I am very new to programming and I have trouble getting the SQL syntax right to join the following two tables (the dots indicate other columns which are not relevant).

T1: Code1, name, ...
T2: Code2, value, ID1, ID2, ...

`SELECT code1, name FROM T1`

--> produces table 1

`SELECT Code2, SUM(value) FROM T2 
WHERE ID1 = X and ID2 = X
GROUP BY Code 2`

--> produces table 2

I now want to join tables 1 and 2 `ON TRIM(T1.code1) = TRIM(T2.code2)` (trim removes spaces causing mismatch).

T1 contains entries that have no value, which I want to appear. So I tried having T1 first and using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, but I can't seem to get it right. Any suggestions?

Thanking you in advance,
George

**EDIT1 - As I haven't stated the platform, the SQL string will be used in MS Access to fill a listbox with the rowsource command.**

**EDIT2 - SAMPLE DATA AND DESIRED RESULTS**

**T1:**

```
Code1   | Name
---------------
1       |  a
2       |  b
3       |  c
4       |  d
```

**T2**

```
Code 2 | Value
---------------
1      |   10
1      |   20
1      |   25
2      |   5
2      |   10
4      |   30
4      |   60
```

**Desired results:**

```
Code  | Name  |  Total
1     |   a   |   55
2     |   b   |   15
3     |   c   |   0 (or NULL)
4     |   d   |   90
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply surround your queries with parentheses:

```
select trim(q1.code1) as code, q1.name, q2.total
from (SELECT code1, name FROM T1 ) q1
left join
(
  SELECT Code2, SUM(value) as total FROM T2 
  WHERE ID1 = X and ID2 = X
  GROUP BY Code2
) q2 on trim(q2.code2) = trim(q1.code1);
```

In your case where you don't have any `WHERE` clause on table1, you can reduce this to:

```
select trim(t1.code1) as code, t1.name, q2.total
from t1
left join
(
  SELECT Code2, SUM(value) as total FROM T2 
  WHERE ID1 = X and ID2 = X
  GROUP BY Code2
) q2 on trim(q2.code2) = trim(t1.code1);
```

Comment: You have a q2.total column in the first line. Should SUM(value) change to SUM(value) as total?

Comment: Yes, I made that `SUM(value) as total`, so the sum has a name I can access.

Comment: Something I haven't mentioned and may be important is that this is on MS-access VBA. The problem seems to be that q2.total column is not recognised. Btw I am working with the simplified 2nd example

Comment: What error message are you getting? In MS Access it may be mandatory to use `AS` for table aliases, hence `) AS q2 on trim(q2.code2) = trim(t1.code1);`.

Comment: Thanks, I actually though about that and tried the AS just in case, but it didn't work. The error is "The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.". I am assuming the error relates to `q2.total` as both queries work if I try them separately.

Comment: Hm, no idea. Do you still get the error when you `select *` instead?

Comment: Yes, but that was an extremely useful idea! Getting the same error meant that the problem was not with T3 naming. I didn't copy paste and accidentally typed `value` instead of `total`. Which was a reserved name. Both `) T3` and `) AS T3` work btw.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your query could be:

```
SELECT T1.code1, T1.name, T3.tot
FROM T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT Code2, SUM([value]) AS tot
    FROM T2 WHERE ID1 = X and ID2 = X
    GROUP BY Code2) T3
ON TRIM(T1.code1) = TRIM(T3.code2)
```

Comment: Non-matching column types.

Comment: similar to the answer above I seem to have trouble with the `T3.value` column. I don't know if this is what @ jarlh is referering to in the above comment.

Comment: Maybe you are forced to put aliases between quotes? Like `AS 'value'` instead of `AS value` and `'T3'` instead of `T3`? Also try to put "value" between square parentheses, just in case.

Comment: @George: No, jarlh's comment referred to nonzaprej's original answer which was completely different from the current one.

Comment: Yeah, at first I completely misunderstood the question.

Comment: Ok. Looking at your code it seems I was copying yours and not @Thorsten. The error related to `AS value`. It cannot be used in MS access. `AS total` worked. Value did not clash with an existing name btw, as I simplified the names here. My tables are linked tables and have hard to read names.